# How Singleton bean can be Autowired in different places spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm confused at this point, and i know all spring boot applications beans are singleton, according to my understanding if we have class annotated with `@Service` annotation that bean can be `@Autowired` in only one class (correct me if i'm wrong) here is the code that works fine, but i'm trying to understand how it works? how one bean can be `@Autowired` in two different classes?

How `SampleService` bean can be `@Autowired` in `SampleController2` and `SampleController3` at a time ?

And is this recommended approach? and in this case two threads can parallely change the data inside bean?

`SampleController2`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="samplemock")
public class SampleController2 {

@Autowired
private SampleService2 sampleservice2;

@RequestMapping(value="/mock1",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void mockCall1() {
    sampleservice2.m1();
   }

}
```

`SampleController3`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="samplemock2")
public class SampleController3 {

@Autowired
private SampleService2 sampleservice2;

@RequestMapping(value="/mock1",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void mockCall1() {
    sampleservice2.m1();

   }
 }
```

`SampleService2`

```
@Service
 public class SampleService2 {

public void m1() {
    System.out.println("bean is autowired");
    }
 }
```

Comment: To understand this you have to understand dependency injection. Dependency injection is the concept behind the keyword Autowired. In other words, sampleService2 variable  in both controllers are simple declarations which means that there is no instance object associated. Keep in mind that Spring core is responsible to create the instances separately when the need is felt.

Comment: i went through dependency injection, you mean it will create two instances? or a single instance ?

Comment: just because something is a singleton doesn't mean it can be only used in one place. you can have the same instance used in two different places

Comment: definitely, it will create two instances are created because those beans are not necessarily invoked at the same time.

Comment: @Solace, can you give me some more info? how does singleton bean can be autowired in different places? just i want to explain in few words, there is a singleton bean and it is associated with reference in controller1, again how can same bean associated with controller2 reference?

Comment: Sure. So behind the scenes Spring manages a "container" with all of the beans that you declare. It only stores a single copy of each bean (the singleton instance). When you autowire something, you are simply getting the copy stored in the container. So you can autowire a bean in as many places as you want, but the same instance in that container is the one that is always getting retrieved

Comment: If you want to verify it, try out this experiment. Autowire your bean in two different places. Then use the postconstruct annotation to run a function after bean creation and print out your autowired bean. You should see a memory address printed out. Now do this again in the second place you autowired that bean. The memory addresses will be the same (indicating that they refer to the same object in memory).

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable information @Solace, i have one more question, according to my understanding when ever spring container starts, it will create beans and save a copy (singleton), so when ever request comes operations will be performed on bean and save back the updated copy, am i right? what if at a time two threads requested the bean? how the one thread bean updates reflect to another thread ?

Comment: the scenario you're describing is no different from. List l1 = new ArrayList(); List l2 = l1; List l3 = l1. If you mutate l2 or l3, you will see all the changes because l2 and l3 are referencing the same object under the hood (the original l1)

Comment: (but ideally beans should be stateless)

Comment: Thank you @Solace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a *simplified* view of what Spring does on startup:

```
// Create bean: sampleService2
SampleService2 sampleService2 = new SampleService2();

// Create bean: sampleController2
SampleController2 sampleController2 = new SampleController2();
sampleController2.sampleservice2 = sampleService2; // because @Autowired

// Create bean: sampleController3
SampleController3 sampleController3 = new SampleController3();
sampleController3.sampleservice2 = sampleService2; // because @Autowired
```

As you can see, the singleton bean `sampleService2` is autowired into both `sampleController2` and `sampleController3`.

The beans are added to a repository, so you can look them up by name or type at any later point in time.

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable information @Andreas, i have one more question, according to my understanding when ever spring container starts, it will create beans and save a copy (singleton), so when ever request comes operations will be performed on bean and save back the updated copy, am i right? what if at a time two threads requested the bean? how the one thread bean updates reflect to another thread ?

Comment: @Deadpool Most singleton beans are stateless, i.e. after setup they are immutable. A web request is processed by a controller (and a service), but the beans themselves are not updated. --- Also, *"save back the updated **copy**"* implies more than one instance, which violates the **singleton** aspect. All requests are processed in parallel by a single instance, but since the instance is stateless, there are no multi-threading issues.

Comment: Thank you @Andres, correct me if i'm wrong, spring bean are singleton and immutable,but properties inside bean can be updated by multiple threads and it is developer responsibility to deal that, so in this case what happen if one thread updating some instance property of that bean and second thread is requesting bean at that time?

Comment: @Deadpool You are wrong. Spring bean being **immutable** means that they don't update fields of the bean, because if they did, they wouldn't be immutable. Since most singleton beans are intended to process web requests in parallel, they should always be stateless, i.e. immutable, ensuring they are always thread-safe. --- What do you mean by *"second thread is **requesting** bean"*? Normally, all beans are autowired together, and hence connected at startup, so there is no "requesting" of beans at request-time, since they already have access to each other.

Comment: Thank you so much @Andreas, i think i'm confusing at `stateless and `stateful`, but i got it now thanks you

Answer (score 4):

By default, as you mentioned, all Spring beans are singletons, but your second assumption is wrong: the same bean can be autowired in many other beans.

In fact that's the whole point of them being singletons.

That also means two different threads could change the state of the same bean indeed. You would most of the time want to keep your beans stateless for that reason.

If you really ever need to have one different instance of a bean for each place where it is autowired, you can change the scope of that bean to `prototype`. See [Spring bean scopes docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html).

Comment: you mean prototype? could you please give an example or link? so where i can get more info

Comment: can you give me some more info? how does singleton bean can be autowired in different places? just i want to explain in few words, there is a singleton bean and it is associated with reference in controller1, again how can same bean associated with controller2 reference?

Answer (score 0):

The intention behind dependency injection and inversion of control is simple:

- You define your injectables (like services) **once**, and they are **instantiated once** (unless you specify otherwise).
- Those injectables are then **used everywhere applicable**, and you don't control their lifecycle, scope or state.

While I feel like the last point answers your primary question fairly tacitly, I'll elaborate - in a DI context, the only thing that really matters are enforceable contracts.  That is to say, if your service subscribes to a specific type of contract, and you have a component which wishes to inject a service which fulfills that contract, then your DI layer should faithfully register a service which can fulfill that contract.

You get into fun and exciting stuff with bean priority, qualifiers and application profiles at that point, but this is the general idea.

For a concrete example:  `javax.sql.DataSource` is an interface which is implemented by many JDBC-backed solutions, such as MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, and others.  If you wish to have two different beans which talk to two different databases, but you want to be able to use those interchangeably, then you define a bean of type `DataSource` to use and configure *which* data source gets created.  Again, this does involve things like `@Qualifier` to ensure you wire in the most specific bean at the most appropriate time.

Also, that last point is fairly important to answer this part of your question:

> ... and in this case two threads can parallely change the data inside bean?

It is ***very*** unwise to create an injectable bean with its own inherent state.  That is, if you have `SampleService` attach itself to some sort of cached state with a collection inside of it, you're basically violating expectations since you don't know when or how often that collection is going to have elements added to it or removed from it.

The better convention is to have beans which can reference stateful services, but don't store that state in the bean itself (such as a database connection, but not entire database tables).